# Where can I store counters in PHP + MySQL website?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

On my Laravel website, people can comment on items, like them and perform some other activities that are counted. I display those counters and order items by them.

What are possible, clean and efficient ways to store these counters? For now, I have created separate columns in database, but I'm not huge fan of this idea. While it's comfortable to browse in database client and efficient, I don't like the fact that my database is polluted with, well, no-data.

How are websites solving that problem today?

Comment: I guess you have separate tables for likes/comments that have foreign key to your items, so why not just select all comments for specific item and count them without need to save "counts"

Comment: Because that would be inneficient to count them each time for sorting. Am I right on that one?

Comment: True, then the only way that I see is what you said, have count column in items for comments/likes

Comment: Generally that is considered fine except for the largest scale applications. Indexes should make counting items reasonably efficient.

Comment: What is largest scale? Is is fine to have million records and count related records for each to order them? I have some doubts. And million is not the largest scale.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a table named `like` (with columns `post_id`, `user_id`).
Though this question is not about laravel itself, a good [example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) of such implementation is provided in the latest docs.

**TLDR;**
Generally, there is two possible implementations. When I have not very much entities (say posts and comments) then I prefer create 2 tables named `post_like` and `comment_like` with `post_id / comment_id` and `user_id` foreign keys. In the case of having lots of different likeable entities it might be a good idea to create one table `like` with columns `foreign_id`, `user_id` and `type`.

If you are thinking about creating an array of users who upvoted / downvoted your post, then stop do it and spend a minute to read about [referential integrity](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/2248101/Referential-Integrity-in-MySQL.htm).

Comment: Just to add: in the case you have a really large scale application nosql databases should do the trick regarding perfomance.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what my question is about. You talk basics of database design, but I'm asking about more advanced solutions to this problem.

Comment: @RoboRobok then you probably wanted to say that you've created separate tables in your database, not columns. I have reread your question several times more and still can't see get what another answer you are looking for.

Comment: There are far more sophisticated ways to store data than database. Whether you have separate table or not doesn't matter. There are things like redis, caches, queues - I wonder what solutions are most suitable for this problem.

Comment: The answer is simple - do the storage in DB, cache in Redis, memcached or whatever

Comment: @RoboRobok what do you mean by queues? You could use sql/nosql DB and cache, if you need. It doesn't matter what you will be using: memcache, memcached, redis as a cache storage or even replications - it is still DB + cache. I can't get what are you expecting to hear more of it.